# submit form cause validation error in other form

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery-validate

i have post detail page (asp.net, umbraco cms), with search box and post replay box.
the problem is that when user try to search using the search box, it cause validation error in the post replay box.
the search is client side form.
the post replay is server side form.
you can view it live at:
http://www.thereturnvalue.com/blog/2010/10/1/return-value-live%27n%27kickin

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Specify different [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx)s on the validators in the different forms (search and post reply).

[Introduction on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx).

Comment: i didnt use validation controls, i used jquery validation.

Comment: thanks i solved the problem - i didn't noticed that all the code was inside other form from the master template. thanks!